# Order() isn't ordering correctly [SOLVED]

Tags: r

I have a tibble with 122 "vp_initial", which themselves consist of ~4 "nr_entry". I want to have the data ordered as followed:

| vp_initial | nr_entry | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 211011 | 1 | 1 |
| 211011 | 2 | 2 |
| 211011 | 3 | 3 |
| 211011 | 4 | 4 |
| 211016 | 1 | 5 |
| 211016 | 2 | 6 |
| 211016 | 3 | 7 |
| 211016 | 4 | 8 |

However, instead he's giving me sth. like this:

| vp_initial | nr_entry | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 211011 | 1 | 309 |
| 211011 | 2 | 375 |
| 211011 | 3 | 415 |
| 211011 | 4 | 105 |
| 211016 | 1 | 146 |
| 211016 | 2 | 248 |
| 211016 | 3 | 345 |
| 211016 | 4 | 231 |

I've already had correctly assigned the nr_entry to each vp_initial, so I did the following:

```
mds$vp_initial <- as.numeric(mds$vp_initial)
mds$nr_entry <- as.numeric(mds$nr_entry)

mds$order <- order(mds$vp_initial, mds$nr_entry)
mds <- mds %>% relocate(order, .after=vp_initial)
```

Consulting the following thread didn't help, as the variables in question ARE numeric: [Order() function in r is not ordering correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399518/order-function-in-r-is-not-ordering-correctly)

What mistake did I do and what do I need to do to order correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `order` is not doing what you think it is. Try e.g. `order(c(3, 7, 2))` and compare that to `sort(c(3, 7, 2))`. Also `relocate` changes the columns, not the rows. 

Try `mds %>% arrange(vp_initial)`

Comment: @Erefin, please, edit your question to make it reproducible: sample data, the code and the desired output. Since you're using `tibble`, `arrange` should be what you need, as suggested by @cett.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I wanted to also generate a variable 'order' which enumerates the rows correctly, as shown in Table 1. I used 'mds$order <- mds %>% arrange(vp_initials)' which reproduced every variable with an "order$" before every variable's name and arranged them correctly. However, no extra 'order' variable was produced, which is what I need. I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post sample data, I guess that would take my PIs consent, thus talking a few days wait time.

Comment: In that case you need the `rank` function, which again, is different from `order` and `sort`

Comment: I've tried `mds$arrange <- mds %>% rank(vp_initials)` but he gives me the following message: "Object 'vp_initials' not found." However,  `mds$arrange <- mds %>% arrange(vp_initials)` works, though it doesn't give me the variable which I need.

Comment: `mds$rank <- rank(mds$vp_initials)` or simpler: `mds %>% arrange(vp_initials) %>% mutate(rank = 1:n())`: this creates a new column `rank` in your data frame.

Comment: I've run the same exact code as beforehand without changing anything, i.e. `mds$arrange <- mds %>% rank(vp_initials)` but this time R DIDN't produce an error message - I guess it might be because of the constellations of some planets :-p Now everything works properly! I've ended up with the following solution: `mds <- mds %>% arrange(vp_initials) 
mds$row <- seq_along(mds$vp_initials)
mds <- mds %>% relocate(row, .after=vp_initials)` Thank you again for your help and your patience!